# joining with a group by and pivot

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, max

I have two tables as below

tbl1

```
id     qNum
1      1
2      2
3      3
```

tbl2

```
id    qNum    displayNum
1     1       3
2     2       1
3     2       2
4     2       4
```

Ideally I need a sql results to look like this

```
qNum    display1    display2    display3    display4
1       0           0           1           0
2       1           1           0           1
3       0           0           0           0
```

I have tried the following sql but this was not correct

```
SELECT
tbl1.qNum,
CASE when tbl2.displayNum=1 then 1 else 0 end AS filter1,
CASE when tbl2.displayNum=2 then 1 else 0 end AS filter2,
CASE when tbl2.displayNum=3 then 1 else 0 end AS filter3,
CASE when tbl2.displayNum=4 then 1 else 0 end AS filter4,
CASE when tbl2.displayNum=5 then 1 else 0 end AS filter5
FROM
tbl1
Left Join tbl2 ON tbl1.qNum = tbl2.qNum
GROUP BY
tbl1.qNum
```

Could anyone help a little please!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is almost correct, you're just missing an aggregate function:

```
SELECT
tbl1.qNum,
MAX(CASE when tbl2.displayNum=1 then 1 else 0 end) AS filter1,
MAX(CASE when tbl2.displayNum=2 then 1 else 0 end) AS filter2,
MAX(CASE when tbl2.displayNum=3 then 1 else 0 end) AS filter3,
MAX(CASE when tbl2.displayNum=4 then 1 else 0 end) AS filter4,
MAX(CASE when tbl2.displayNum=5 then 1 else 0 end) AS filter5
FROM
tbl1
Left Join tbl2 ON tbl1.qNum = tbl2.qNum
GROUP BY
tbl1.qNum
```

The columns you select should always be either in the group by clause or an aggregate function should be applied to them. A group by "collapses" a group of rows and if you don't have an aggregate function on a column (which is not in the group by) a random row of that group is displayed.

Here you can read about the different aggregate functions: [GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

The MAX() function in our case here returns the greatest value (note: not the row with the greatest value. You can also have a query like this: `select min(col), max(col) from whatever`).

Comment: As an aside, what does the aggregate function do that makes it work?

Comment: @Dave Explanation added in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have use `MAX` function to pivot the table

Try this:

```
SELECT tbl1.qNum,
       MAX(CASE WHEN tbl2.displayNum=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS filter1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN tbl2.displayNum=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS filter2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN tbl2.displayNum=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS filter3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN tbl2.displayNum=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS filter4,
       MAX(CASE WHEN tbl2.displayNum=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS filter5
FROM tbl1
LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.qNum = tbl2.qNum
GROUP BY tbl1.qNum
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to point out that in MySQL, you can simplify the expression.  It doesn't need a `case` statement because booleans are treated as integers with values of 0 and 1:

```
SELECT tbl1.qNum,
       MAX(tbl2.displayNum = 1) AS filter1,
       MAX(tbl2.displayNum = 2) AS filter2,
       MAX(tbl2.displayNum = 3) AS filter3,
       MAX(tbl2.displayNum = 4) AS filter4,
       MAX(tbl2.displayNum = 5) AS filter5
FROM tbl1 Left Join
     tbl2
     ON tbl1.qNum = tbl2.qNum
GROUP BY tbl1.qNum;
```

Normally, I prefer going with ANSI standard syntax.  I do, however, find this easier to read than the `case` syntax.

Also, you may not need `tbl1` for the query, if all values you are interested in are already in `tbl2`.